# How to setHeader for jwt token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to set the header for the JWT token that prints into the body on Postman. I would like some help to what I should add as I'm quite new to this jwt token stuff. I want to add a new "Authorization" header with the Bearer token.

```
package com.example.jwtspringsecurity.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/register", "/auth").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/**")
                .authenticated().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.jwtspringsecurity.controller;

import com.example.jwtspringsecurity.dto.AuthenticationRequest;
import com.example.jwtspringsecurity.dto.AuthenticationResponse;
import com.example.jwtspringsecurity.service.jwt.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import com.example.jwtspringsecurity.util.JwtUtil;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public AuthenticationResponse createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, HttpServletResponse response) throws BadCredentialsException, DisabledException, UsernameNotFoundException, IOException {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getEmail(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "user not created. Register first");
            return null;
        }
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getEmail());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails.getUsername());
        response.setHeader("Authorization" ,jwt);

        return new AuthenticationResponse(jwt);
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.jwtspringsecurity.util;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class JwtUtil {
    public static final String SECRET = "5367566B59703373367639792F423F4528482B4D6251655468576D5A71347437";

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts
                .parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

    public String generateToken(String userName){
        Map<String,Object> claims=new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims,userName);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String userName) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setSubject(userName)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000*60*30))
                .signWith(getSignKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256).compact();
    }

    private Key getSignKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes= Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

}
```

These are my configurate for the security api but let me know if you would like to see other code snippets. Thank you.

Comment: You have already set the `jwt` token in AuthenticationResponse object so why you need to set it into a header??

Comment: This is actually for a social media clone project where the token would not set in the header as that’s where my frontend calls to the backend to check the token so I did a smaller one to check how to set it in the header

Comment: you can use ResponseEntity class for setting up the `Authorization` like 
`ResponseEntity.ok() .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt).body(response);` as given by `@Angshuman` below.

Answer (score 1):

In the RestController `createAuthenticationToken` method, you are sending a `AuthenticationResponse` object (which I assume is a DTO class) and not the `HttpServletResponse` object where you have actually set the `Authorization` header. So, the `jwt` token is being sent in the body of the response only and not in the header. I have modified your code to send the token in both the body and the header. To send it only in the header, simply send `null` in the body.

```java
@RestController
public class AuthController {
    
    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws BadCredentialsException, DisabledException, UsernameNotFoundException {
        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getEmail(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (DisabledException disabledException) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "User not created. Register first");
        }
        
        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getEmail());
        final String jwt = jwtUtil.generateToken(userDetails.getUsername());
        
        AuthenticationResponse response = new AuthenticationResponse(jwt);
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt)
                .body(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: The .body(response) works but the .header() doesn't. Is it because I have to return a new response entity?

Comment: Could you show the response from the API including the Header? That will make things more clear.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Only saw this post now. But I figured out that I had to paste the authorization string in header and then it resets.